# AAPT Error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

I have looked at the previous answers for this question but the AAPT error still occurs.

```
error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'org.emarti202.gcu.mpd-cw-em'.
```

Despite my applicationId in the build.gradle and the package names in the AndroidManifest.xml match, they still do not work. Is there a solution for this? Apologies is this is a simple fix, I cant seem to wrap my head around it.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.emarti202.gcu.mpd-cw-em">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MPD-CW-EM"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_key" />

        <activity android:name="org.emarti202.gcu.mpd-cw-em.MainActivity2"></activity>
        <activity android:name="org.emarti202.gcu.mpd-cw-em.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.emarti202.gcu.mpd-cw-em"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.alespero:expandable-cardview:0.6'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the hyphen '-' is not acceptable in a package name.
Please reference this docs.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package

> A full Java-language-style package name for the Android app. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.
> While building your app into the an application package (APK), the build system uses the package attribute for two things

Please change your package name to 'org.emarti202.gcu.mpd_cw_em'.

Comment: Ah I see! Sorry about that Daniel, thank you for helping me out!

Comment: no problem, So, you can't use anything else except for letters, digits, the character "." and the character "_" .